# Use an Id to associate an existing array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select

I have a question (and a problem) in JavaScript.

I want to use an ID for a option list:

```
<select id="map_select">
<option value="1" id="test1" >Test 1</option>
<option value="2" id="test2" >Test 2</option>
</select>
```

And associate this ID to an existing Array in JavaScript:

```
var test1 = ["blabla 1","blabla 2"]
var test2 = ["blabla 1","blabla 2"]
```

I tried something in jQuery:

```
var selec = $('#map_select option:selected').attr('id');
```

But when I use it in a function I need (which need an array with push, indexof...), it did not refer to my array:

```
function tabused(tab1, tab2){

    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*tab2.length)

    if(tab1.length <= tab2.length){
                if (tab1.indexOf(rand) === -1) {
                    tab1.push(rand);
                } 
                else if (tab1.indexOf(rand) > -1) {
                    while(tab1.indexOf(rand) > -1){
                        rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(tab2.length-1));
                    }
                    tab1.push(rand);
                }
                console.log(tab1)
            }
            $("#rules").text(tab2[rand])
}
```

Please can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if it does not refer to array , where it does refer?

Comment: you are trying to *bind* the array as the options for the `select`?

Comment: Try `window[selec];`

Comment: Acutally, i want to load an array when people change the select value, so i create Option with Id and array with same name as the id, but i don't know how to load my array in a function like - function test(array)  :(

Comment: @Lucas Well where is this function you speak of? Would it not be relevant to your question to include it?

Comment: If you want there is a short exemple of my function : https://ibb.co/gdWXXF
I'm not really good in Js or jQuery, i'm learning by trying stuff :/

Comment: I'm not opening unknown links. I'm here to help others and since you are the one looking for the help I would recommend you follow the rules of Stack Overflow and include the relevant source code to your question. Also an image of the source code would mean others have to type it all out, why make more work for those willing to help....

Comment: I Understand, and i'm sorry, i'm french, i didn't read all the rules of Stack Overflow ! Not gonna happen again :) !

I updated my question with the function

Comment: How and where is `tabused(tab1, tab2)` called and what does `tab1` and `tab2` contain.... if you can create a minimal working example that would be great because at the moment you aren't including the relevant source to give you a solid answer. If your attempt with `var selec = $('#map_select option:selected').attr('id');` is returning the expected value then use my previous suggestion. Test it by `console.log(window[selec]);` simple Example: https://jsfiddle.net/L1bheeuo/

Comment: Someone found the solution ! Sorry for few information :/
But thanks for your time and your help !

Comment: I see, that's a little different to your question as that is an object but no doubt best you use that method.

Comment: As i said, i'm learning JS and i don't know the best way to do things, so thanks for advice !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but i think an id cant be referenced to a data structure in js just like that.

You could try using a dictionary in place.

```
var test= {
            "test1":["blabla 1","blabla 2"],
            "test2":["blabla 1","blabla 2"]
          };
```

While using you could just search your id as a key to dictionary.

```
var selec = $('#map_select option:selected').attr('id');
console.log(test[selec]);
```

Comment: It's working ! It look easy but i did not think about doing this by this way, so thanks a lot dude ! :)

And sorry for few information, next time i will do better :) !

Comment: A great suggestion and a better way of doing it. Using an object is better than multiple arrays. **+1**